# What command can I input to print out my terminal interface?

Tags: terminal, printing

As you can see my attached image on this thread, I am using a software called FORM from nikhef for my qft homework. I need to print out the result, which is outputed in the linux terminal for my homework.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3tEu.png)

Comment: Pipe the command to `lp -`.

Comment: "...print out the result" as in the exit code from the previous command?
  `echo $?` will give you the exit code.  Please clarify.

Comment: I want to find a way to "PAPER PRINT" all the mathematical formulae that were outputed in the terminal.

Comment: As far as lp command is concerned, how can I look up what are my options for printer to connect?

Comment: You're probably running your printers through CUPS. If you browse to http://localhost:631 and click on Printers, you should be able to see all your printers and list some of the settings for each of them. For more direct control, try installing and running `xpp`. It lets you set everything under the sun about a particular printer and even save the results for future use as a printer instance.

Comment: As @jordanm suggests, pipes are your friends in situations like this. You can also use io redirection (`>`) to save the output of a command to a file so you can edit out any cruft or even reformat it for readability, etc. That formula - `m2=` ... is serious write-only code that really needs some reformatting if it ever needs to be maintained or debugged.